# Is there a way in Flow to extract subtype definitions from a disjoint union type?

Tags: types, flowtype

Let's say I have the following disjoint union type:

```
type UnionType = {type: 'A', foo: string} | {type: 'B', bar: number}
```

and I want to extract type definitions for the subtypes:

```
type SubTypeA = {type: 'A', foo: string}
type SubTypeB = {type: 'B', bar: number}
```

but I want to extract them only based on their `type` value, and without having to re-define the entire subtype. I want to have type definitons for these subtypes so I can have functions that are annotated with the subtypes, i.e.:

```
    handleSubTypeA = (item: SubTypeA) => {
        <do stuff>
    };
```

Comment: Why not assign the subtypes and then do `type UnionType = SubTypeA | SubTypeB;`? It seems a lot clearer that way.

Comment: Good question -- this is what I would do generally, but the codebase I'm working in creates (quite complex) auto-generated types based on GraphQL queries. Our best solution when dealing with disjoint unions currently is, as you suggested, explicitly re-defining the subtypes. But I'm hoping there is a DRYer solution out there.